# memory leaks shown by valgrind to gtk init call

Tags: memory-leaks, gtk, valgrind

I am trying check memory leaks in my code, and valgrind is showing many error. As I have never used valgrind before, I need help. 
To start with, I am concentrating to the default gtk call's. 
as coded, memory is leaked from mkbib.c's line number 140. But line number 140 is just

```
gtk_init(&argc, &argv);
```

I have used

```
G_SLICE=always-malloc G_DEBUG=gc-friendly valgrind --tool=memcheck 
--leak-check=full --leak-resolution=high --num-callers=20 
--log-file=vgdump --suppressions=gtk.suppression ./mkbib
```

which, along with gtk.suppression is taken from [valgrind-gnome Live](https://live.gnome.org/Valgrind)

```
==28420== 16 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 2,413 of 10,955
==28420==    at 0x4A0887C: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:270)
==28420==    by 0x310CA4D68E: g_malloc (in /usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.3400.2)
==28420==    by 0x311C611176: ??? (in /usr/lib64/libatk-bridge-2.0.so.0.0.0)
==28420==    by 0x311C60C19D: atk_bridge_adaptor_init (in /usr/lib64/libatk-bridge-2.0.so.0.0.0)
==28420==    by 0x311D50257B: ??? (in /usr/lib64/libgtk-3.so.0.600.4)
==28420==    by 0x311D38D6FA: ??? (in /usr/lib64/libgtk-3.so.0.600.4)
==28420==    by 0x310CA52FB6: g_option_context_parse (in /usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.3400.2)
==28420==    by 0x311D38DBCD: gtk_parse_args (in /usr/lib64/libgtk-3.so.0.600.4)
==28420==    by 0x311D38DC28: gtk_init_check (in /usr/lib64/libgtk-3.so.0.600.4)
==28420==    by 0x311D38DC58: gtk_init (in /usr/lib64/libgtk-3.so.0.600.4)
==28420==    by 0x403F65: main (mkbib.c:140)
==28420== 
==28420== 16 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 2,414 of 10,955
==28420==    at 0x4A0887C: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:270)
==28420==    by 0x310CA4D68E: g_malloc (in /usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.3400.2)
==28420==    by 0x311C611176: ??? (in /usr/lib64/libatk-bridge-2.0.so.0.0.0)
==28420==    by 0x311C60C1DD: atk_bridge_adaptor_init (in /usr/lib64/libatk-bridge-2.0.so.0.0.0)
==28420==    by 0x311D50257B: ??? (in /usr/lib64/libgtk-3.so.0.600.4)
==28420==    by 0x311D38D6FA: ??? (in /usr/lib64/libgtk-3.so.0.600.4)
==28420==    by 0x310CA52FB6: g_option_context_parse (in /usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.3400.2)
==28420==    by 0x311D38DBCD: gtk_parse_args (in /usr/lib64/libgtk-3.so.0.600.4)
==28420==    by 0x311D38DC28: gtk_init_check (in /usr/lib64/libgtk-3.so.0.600.4)
==28420==    by 0x311D38DC58: gtk_init (in /usr/lib64/libgtk-3.so.0.600.4)
==28420==    by 0x403F65: main (mkbib.c:140)
==28420== 
==28420== 24 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 3,468 of 10,955
==28420==    at 0x4A0887C: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:270)
==28420==    by 0x310CA4D68E: g_malloc (in /usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.3400.2)
==28420==    by 0x310CA63F65: g_memdup (in /usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.3400.2)
==28420==    by 0x310D22D274: ??? (in /usr/lib64/libgobject-2.0.so.0.3400.2)
==28420==    by 0x310D22DFCC: g_type_class_ref (in /usr/lib64/libgobject-2.0.so.0.3400.2)
==28420==    by 0x311D5022C7: ??? (in /usr/lib64/libgtk-3.so.0.600.4)
==28420==    by 0x311A6154C8: atk_add_focus_tracker (in /usr/lib64/libatk-1.0.so.0.20609.1)
==28420==    by 0x311D502567: ??? (in /usr/lib64/libgtk-3.so.0.600.4)
==28420==    by 0x311D38D6FA: ??? (in /usr/lib64/libgtk-3.so.0.600.4)
==28420==    by 0x310CA52FB6: g_option_context_parse (in /usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.3400.2)
==28420==    by 0x311D38DBCD: gtk_parse_args (in /usr/lib64/libgtk-3.so.0.600.4)
==28420==    by 0x311D38DC28: gtk_init_check (in /usr/lib64/libgtk-3.so.0.600.4)
==28420==    by 0x311D38DC58: gtk_init (in /usr/lib64/libgtk-3.so.0.600.4)
==28420==    by 0x403F65: main (mkbib.c:140)
==28420== 
==28420== 24 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 3,469 of 10,955
==28420==    at 0x4A06B6F: calloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:593)
==28420==    by 0x310CA4D6E6: g_malloc0 (in /usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.3400.2)
==28420==    by 0x310D22DF00: g_type_class_ref (in /usr/lib64/libgobject-2.0.so.0.3400.2)
==28420==    by 0x310D22DD4E: g_type_class_ref (in /usr/lib64/libgobject-2.0.so.0.3400.2)
==28420==    by 0x310D21E7BF: g_param_spec_flags (in /usr/lib64/libgobject-2.0.so.0.3400.2)
==28420==    by 0x311D4C27BB: ??? (in /usr/lib64/libgtk-3.so.0.600.4)
==28420==    by 0x310D22E0B5: g_type_class_ref (in /usr/lib64/libgobject-2.0.so.0.3400.2)
==28420==    by 0x311D5022C7: ??? (in /usr/lib64/libgtk-3.so.0.600.4)
==28420==    by 0x311A6154C8: atk_add_focus_tracker (in /usr/lib64/libatk-1.0.so.0.20609.1)
==28420==    by 0x311D502567: ??? (in /usr/lib64/libgtk-3.so.0.600.4)
==28420==    by 0x311D38D6FA: ??? (in /usr/lib64/libgtk-3.so.0.600.4)
==28420==    by 0x310CA52FB6: g_option_context_parse (in /usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.3400.2)
==28420==    by 0x311D38DBCD: gtk_parse_args (in /usr/lib64/libgtk-3.so.0.600.4)
==28420==    by 0x311D38DC28: gtk_init_check (in /usr/lib64/libgtk-3.so.0.600.4)
==28420==    by 0x311D38DC58: gtk_init (in /usr/lib64/libgtk-3.so.0.600.4)
==28420==    by 0x403F65: main (mkbib.c:140)
```

I have found some discussion that valgrind is not good to detect memory leaks in gtk. is this one of such cases, that I should ignore? or I am missing something?

my system involved is:

1. gtk3-devel-3.6.4-1.fc18.x86_64
2. valgrind-3.8.1-9.fc18.x86_64
3. gcc(GCC) 4.7.2 20121109

Answer (score 1):

For the time being you should concentrate on the leaks detected explicitely in your part of the code. Valgrind often finds leaks on external components you cannot modify, even commercial libraries. You can consult the documentation for ignore files, they suppres output of errors coming from certain libraries:
http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core.html#manual-core.suppress

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But as you can see, I have used the suppression as adviced by gtk itself. But those leaks are still there.

Comment: I had a look at the suppression file, and though I am no expert, I think your error is not covered in it. It has no line containing the right library, allthough there are lines containing the correct function, but in another library. Maybe you could generate another suppression file or add the needed suppression to the existing one.

Answer (score 1):

Try modifying suppression file to be more generic, excerpted example:

   `...
   obj:/usr/lib64/libgtk*       (issue seems to apply to any gtk version, including gtk-2)
   fun:g_option_context_parse
   fun:gtk_parse_args           (or could just use "...")
   fun:gtk_init*                (also applies to gtk_init_check)`